Writing a Master's thesis "pre-proposal" in pure math
I've recently learned that I have to write a Master's thesis pre-proposal for my application to the ETH Zürich scholarship program ESOP. This is basically a thesis proposal, but written before one even starts the Master's degree. The issue is that my intent is to apply to a pure math program and I imagine a thesis in this to be significantly different than a thesis in, say, some natural science.
For one, I'd imagine a lot of prerequisite knowledge is required to even understand what my thesis is aiming for. For example, if I wanted to write a thesis on the implications of some advanced theorem, a big part of my Master's would presumably be getting familiar with that theorem, learning the proof, etc. I can maybe get a "big picture" understanding in a short amount of time, but would this be an acceptable thing to do? I am basically saying that I plan to do work on this topic without even knowing much of anything about the topic.
Also, I'm not sure where I could arrive at an idea for the proposal. I've heard that one could read papers in the field, but what concretely am I supposed to do? The paper could say: "This result of ours poses an interesting question: [question]" and I'd presumably have no way of evaluating how difficult it could be to answer that question without getting intimately familiar with the topic, which I can not do, as I'm not even supposed to know much about the topic yet. Or are there cases where this is not an issue? You can see how this is not a big problem in, say, biology. If a paper said that it'd be interesting to study certain proteins of whatever, I can be confident that I can measure and observe some stuff under a microscope in a 6-month timeframe. Not so much here.
As a related question, what role does previous research experience play in math? I see it talked about a lot, but someone currently doing a Bachelor's degree in math seems to me unable to contribute in any meaningful way to research.

Will ETH give you a sample from the past?

This was one of my first ideas, too, but they don't provide anything publicly and I doubt that they'd give such "inside information" then if asked privately.

@Buffy on second thought, perhaps sending an email is not the worst idea. Do you think this would be acceptable or would it come off as trying to "cheat"?

This is an unusual requirement, but ETH guidelines for this program say that "the Master’s thesis has to be completed within a given time (4-6 months depending on the Master’s programme)," meaning that they expect you to have very strong background in the type of math you are going to work on when at ETH. I am in the US and almost none of the applicants to our math PhD program would be able to do it in a meaningful way. But there are exceptions and my guess is that ESOP fellowship program at ETH is aiming for this kind of exceptional students. Talk to your undergraduate advisor (if you have any) about this. If you can come up with something reasonable, then write down such a proposal. Otherwise, consider applying for different fellowships and maybe even to different institutions.
Regarding your last question: Most of PhD applicants in my department do not have serious math research experience as undergraduates. But, again, there are exceptions, some applicants already have papers submitted to some very good math journals.

I'm unsure as to what exactly you mean by your first paragraph, but I'm pretty sure that the 4-6 months come at the end of the Master's program, so you actually have 1.5 years to learn the material up to this point. This 1.5 years worth of knowledge is where my problem lies. It seems that your interpretation is that this is a proposal for a thesis to be worked on immediately after getting accepted, but I don't think this is the case.

@InformalWay: Then write to the chair of the graduate program at the ETH math department and ask for a clarification. And I am quoting directly from their official document which you should read in any case.

Sorry, but I don't think it's an unclear specification. You probably just misinterpreted because you're not familiar with the specific system, but the Master's program is outlined to be 1.5 years of study and then 6 months for a Master's thesis. This pre-proposal also isn't "binding", after the 1.5 years I will be able to change my mind and submit a totally different proposal for the thesis (in general the pre-proposal can't even serve as a substitute for the real proposal). It's more of a test, the idea being to test whether you can do research well or whatever...

...but AFAIK I will have to prove I actually know something about the topic as there are interviews later where you are asked questions about the pre-proposal. So I have to know something, but not as much as you thought, but, then again, I don't know how much I have to know, and that's a problem.

As a student at ETH, I can confirm that you (typically) have 1.5 years before you start your thesis. This answer is based on a misunderstanding and should be removed.
